# Why update a date and version at word file not working

Tags: jenkins, ms-word, msbuild

In my project i have the following code that find and replace a version number and date at word document but for some reason it's not working. Can i get help from you guys to understand why its not working?
This is a ps1 file that i use at Jenkins + MSBuild.
Thanks

```
<#
Uses Microsoft Word automation to substitute Version and ReleaseDate values, and yield a PDF.
#>
function UpdateDocumentation {
    param (
        [string] $Path,
        [string] $Version,
        [string] $ReleaseDate
    )
    
    $path = Resolve-Path -Path $Path;

    $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application;
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($path);
    $selection = $word.Selection
    $Forward = $MatchWholeWord = $true;
    $Format = $MatchAllWordForms = $MatchCase = $MatchSoundsLike = $MatchWildcards = $Wrap = $false;

    $FindText = "%Version%";
    $ReplaceWith = [System.Version]::Parse($Version).ToString(3);

    $selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format,
            $ReplaceWith, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace]::wdReplaceAll);

    $FindText = "%ReleaseDate%";
    $ReplaceWith = [DateTime]::Today.ToString("MMMM yyyy");

    $selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap, $Format,
            $ReplaceWith, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace]::wdReplaceAll);
        
    $pdf = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($(Resolve-Path $Path), '.pdf');

    $doc.SaveAs($pdf, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatPDF);
    $doc.Close([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions]::wdDoNotSaveChanges);
    $word.Quit();
}
```

and the call to it:

```
UpdateDocumentation -Path '.\assureid-documentation\assureid-word-pdf-docs\assureid-sentinel\AssureID Sentinel Deployment Guide.docx' `
        -Version $Version -ReleaseDate [DateTime]::Today
```

The document contain this text:
Version %VERSION%
%RELEASEDATE%

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar problem with some Excel methods.
Can you try to not defining optional parameters that you don't need to use:

```
$selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null,
        $ReplaceWith, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace]::wdReplaceAll);
```